# select specific word from first 2 lines, starting with specific word, regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

data is pandas Series:
i am using `df.B=df.A.str.extract(r'')`
to create B column with extracted WHERE words
df:

```
A
HI my lines are
so super WHERE1 my car
car go anywhere
next line like this
HI my lines are
so super WHERE2 my car
one WHERE HI like me
```

Data above is test data, between `HI` words there is sometimes 40 lines of space.
I need to get from first two lines starting from HI which is always first.
and from those first lines, get WHERE1 and WHERE2 word

my regex until now:

```
^(HI(.*\n){2}) #to select first two lines
```

i dont know where i should add word that i am looking for (WHERE1|WHERE2)

expected Output:

```
WHERE1
WHERE2
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: two words, WHERE1 and WHERE2

Comment: So you want to get the WHERE1 and WHERE2 after each HI?

Comment: yes, after each HI if HI is starting line

Comment: Why not just simply search for each WHERE1 and WHERE2? Do you need the positions or something else?

Comment: because i dont want each WHERE1 and WHERE2, i want only WHERE when exist in first two lines after HI

Comment: Are you reading this data from a text file or is this a string?

Comment: is pandas series , one column, i am using str.extract() to put it into second column, but i need regex to do that, i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with `MULTILINE` mode:

```
^HI\s.*(?:\n.*)?\b(WHERE1|WHERE2)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y7jclc/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^HI\s`: Match a line starting with `HI` and a whitespace
- `.*`: Match 0 or more o any character
- `(?:\n.*)?`: Optional group to match a line break and 0 or more o any character
- `\b(WHERE1|WHERE2)\b`: Match `WHERE1` or `WHERE2` with word boundaries

Comment: hello again, could you tell me how to extract group(1) from this regex? i am trying to use code as above `df.B=df.A.str.extract(r'^HI\s.*(?:\n.*)?\b(WHERE1|WHERE2)\b').group(1)` but i am receiving an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' , albo this way where i am searching secong line, in case when input is pd.Series is good way to go? maybe i should consider to take into account in this regex rows not lines?

Comment: Does your input start with a line that starts with `Hi`

Comment: Can you open my regex101  demo and paste your full input text there and then provide me updated demo link. Otherwise you cannot copy/paste multiline text in comments.

Comment: its the same text, the point is that i am opening it using pd.Series , and receiving already mentioned error

Comment: I have no idea about `pd.Series`. May be you can try: `r'(?m)^HI\s.*(?:\n.*)?\b(WHERE1|WHERE2)\b'`